# Java - Find words that do not come after a full stop

Tags: regex

I have a large text that i want to find all the words that start with a capital letter inside it but do not come after a full stop, ex :

> This is a general example. Please extract Capitalized words from it.
>
> The extracted words should not have Full Stops before them, even if it is in a new line.

So i want to extract the words "**This**", "**Capitalized**", "**Full**", "**Stops**".

The words "**Please**" & "**The**" should be ignored.

I know the query to index capitalized words is "**[A-Z]{1}[a-z]***", but how to add the requested condition to this query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<!\.\s)[A-Z]\w*
```

assuming there is one whitespace after full stop.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kT4pD5/1)

If that assumption cannot be made and there are multiple or no whitespace after dot then use this regex:

```
\.\s*[A-Z]|([A-Z]\w*)
```

And grab **captured group #1**

#### [RegEx Demo2](http://regex101.com/r/kT4pD5/2)